# Flexible container with a fixed element and many extra variable width elements that should wrap/overflow

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I'm trying to design a layout for HTML elements which is grid-like. I don't need to use the grid if it's not the right choice, I also have tried with flexbox, but I'm never getting the right result.

What I need is to define a container that can have a variable width and height. The width is determined by its parent. The height should depend on its content, that is a variable number of elements, as below:

- The first element (let's call it *main*) is a large element that should stick to the top-left side of the container. This element has a fixed width and height. The parent container may be larger and taller than this element, depending on the rest of the elements explained below.
- A variable number of additional elements (let's call them *extra*), always at least 1, generally around 6-9. I want these extra elements to be on the right of the *main* element, forming one or more rows to its right, and if there is no space left they should wrap below the main element, forming a new row. These extra elements have a height that is always less than the total the height of the *Main* element, so they can be stacked. These elements sometimes have a fixed width, sometimes the width can be variable. If there is not enough space, then they should "overflow" below the Main element, forming one or more new rows.

[image: Example configurations]

I tried using `grid` and flexbox without good results. I think the closest I found myself ot the solution is [using a grid](https://jsfiddle.net/ceu3qt7p/), but it's unsatisfactory as I cannot manage to define flexible width elements.

Comment: Frankly I don't think there is a *system* that will do this. I *feel* that `float` will get you closest to what you want though.